# auto increment list index in python

Tags: list, python-2.7

Watch index `n` ( and `y`)

```
n = 0
while(0 < y):
  result[ n += 1] = items[y -= 1]
```

So the above is accepted syntax. Is there an elegant way to do this, in the order of `Java`'s

```
result[ n++] = items[--y]
```

Comment: @Lev Levitsky, if this helps: for an example of what I am trying to do see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Counting_sort#Python . I am wondering about combining the two steps: `array[i] = a` and 
            `i += 1`. I suppose it may not be such a big deal. Nonetheless that's the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not accepted syntax.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, the pythonic way would be

```
result = items[::-1]
```

or

```
result = list(reversed(items))
```

(the [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) function itself returns an iterator, not a list).

Comment: That's not what I am trying to do. The question is straight forward: auto incrementing the index `n`: `result[ n += 1]`. Thanks for your response, though.

Comment: @kasavbere The point is, in Python you usually don't use indexes in operations like this. In this case you are even avoiding the need of an explicit loop. Using unjustified C-like or Java-like constructs in Python is commonly considered bad practice.